# Mongo DB findOne with multiple arguments

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am developing a website using Meteor JS and I need to update records in my database based on a username.

```
var responseId=userAccounts.findOne({likedPostsId:idToSearch, $where: {username:myUsername}});
```

Basically I want it to return the documents where the likedPostsId match the searched Id and where the username in the collection is the same as the user that is logged in. I am new to Meteor Mongo so probably my syntax is wrong. I would appreciate some help.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Thank you ! It worked !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need `$where` for that and you can simplify it to:

```
userAccounts.findOne({likedPostsId: idToSearch, username: myUsername})
```